# Pandas Removing Leading Zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a short script to pivot data. The first column is a 9 digit ID number, often beginning with zeros such as `000123456`

Here is the script:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('source')

new_df = df.pivot_table(index = 'id', columns = df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1), values = ['prog_id', 'prog_type'], aggfunc='first').sort_index(axis=1,level=1)

new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]

new_df.to_csv('destination')
print(new_df)
```

Although the CSV is being read with an id such as `000123456`, the output only contains `123456`

Even when setting an explicit dtype, Pandas removes the leading zeros. Is there a work around for telling Pandas to leave the leading zeros?

Comment: what do you mean? the `read_csv` function still takes a `dtype` argument to specify column types

Comment: I shouldn't have even added that part, as it's confusing. Even if I specify a dtype using np such as `dtype={'id':np.int32}`, it still removes the leading zeros.

Comment: You should specify the field as a `str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per comment on original post, set dtype as string:

`df = pd.read_csv('source', dtype={'id':np.str})`

Answer (score 2):

You could use pandas' `zfill()` method right after reading your csv file `"source"`. Basically, you would fill the values of your attribute `"id"`, with as many zeros as you would like, in this particular case, making the number 9 digits long (3 zeros + 6 original digits). So, we would have:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('source')

df.index = df.index.str.zfill(9)

# (...)
```